# Load content into div based on month

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am needing to load content for the specific month defined by the user. If the user picks the month of July, a list of events (the content in the this case) is shown for the month of July. If the user picks June, all of the June events are shown. Right now, I have a script set up to where the user clicks a "next" link to switch months. Only month is shown at a time. When the user clicks the "next" link, I would like for all of the next months content to load. For example, if the user is on the month of June and they click next than July will will show up as well as all of the July events. To load the new events I am using:

```
window.location = "/<?php echo $site_slug; ?>/ministries/events/<?php echo $_GET['year']; ?>/<?php echo $_GET['month']; ?>;
```

This is called when the user clicks the "next" button. The $_GET['year'] and $_GET['month'} variables are being populated by an API. When I click the next button, I am not getting the "year" and "month" values but just a hashtag. My question is, is the javascript syntax correct?

EDIT: Added more code:

Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $(".event_months li:nth-child(3)").addClass("doShow");

            $("a.next").click(function() {
                $('.first').toggleClass("first");
                var $toHighlight = $('.doShow').next().length > 0 ? $('.doShow').next() : $('.event_months li').first();
                $('.doShow').removeClass('doShow');
                $toHighlight.addClass('doShow');
                window.location = "/<?php echo $site_slug; ?>/ministries/events/<?php echo $_GET['year']; ?>/<?php echo $_GET['month']; ?>;

            });

          });
     </script>
```

Not sure if the API call will help but here it is:

```
<?php getContent(
    "event",
    "display:list", 
    "order:recent",
    "find_group:".$site_slug,
    "groupby:month",
    "year:".$_GET['year'], 
    "month:".$_GET['month'],
    "group_show:<li class='noShow'>__slug__</li>"
    ); 
?>
```

Comment: What's that trailing `+` doing? Typo?

Comment: Yes, typo. It's corrected now, thanks.

Comment: The code looks like every thing is ok, the question is what do you sending in the variables, show a little more of your code it should be able to answer,

Comment: Can you dump the API to see if there is a string in the get function?

Comment: yeah what does the getContent call display?

Comment: It displays a list of months with events. So if there are events in June, July and August than it will display a list of June, July and August.

Comment: I am not sure if I made this clear but basically I just need to update the url when the user clicks a new month. If they user clicks the "next" button and the next month that shows up is July than I need www.siteurl.com/ministries/events/2012/07 to load.

Comment: I hope you see you're missing quotes in the `window.location` script

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. It's correct in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

I setup your code like you did (I had to guess at the "next" link), and couldn't get it to work. The problem, from what I can tell, is that you're using `$_GET` to get the year and month variables from the URL. Use `$_REQUEST`, instead:

```
<a class="next" href="/?year=2012&month=06" onclick="return false;">Next</a>
```

You'll also need the "return false" to stop the link from following, IF you want to use your window.location line.

Don't forget (like you've mentioned) to make sure your window.location has a closing parenthesis.